# anyone to know meteor js support crystal report or not and how many report support meteor js?

Tags: meteor, crystal-reports, angular-meteor

Hello everyone just to know about meteor js can use crystal report or not and how many type of report support in meteorjs or angular-meteor.
can you help me to integrate report on angular-meteorjs or meteorjs.

Comment: Put the crystal reports into an iframe. That's your best bet with almost any framework.

Comment: hey Michel Floyd. Thanks for giving me such information. Just wanna know using angularjs with Meteor js, Is it Possible to work with that? Have you any example such like using iframe with crystal report? i didn't find any link so need to your help. (we use pouchdb - couchdb database).  Thanks

Comment: Crystal reports has a web viewer iirc. I would just create an iframe in my layout that points to the appropriate CR URL.

Comment: Hi Michel Floyd can you please tell me how to integrate jasper report on meteor js or angular-meteorjs. is it possible to use with meteorjs.

Comment: Never used Jasper. If there's a web view for it then drop it into an iframe as well or as @reckface suggests just open it in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no client side libraries actually "support" Crystal reports. Crystal reports is provided as an Asp.Net Webforms library that  render reports on the server and served to client browsers.

If you write the asp.net page to support parameters, you can integrate with meteorjs or any other client library, by loading the report viewer dynamically.